# Exoplayer analytics total join time - app crashing

Tags: java, android, analytics, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to get the [total join time](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/analytics/PlaybackStats.html#getTotalJoinTimeMs()) in before a video starts using the [Exoplayer Demo App](https://exoplayer.dev/demo-application.html), but the app just crashes when I launch the app with the code for this.

I've initiated the [playback stats listener](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/analytics/PlaybackStats.html) as follows in [PlayerActivity.js](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java)

```
protected PlaybackStatsListener playerStatsListener = new PlaybackStatsListener(true, null);
```

Following that, I add that to my player using addAnalyticsListener

```
player.addAnalyticsListener(playerStatsListener)
```

Within the [onCreate method](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/ab4d37f499ba49bb3cac7938eb03ebf7133ccfe6/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L105), I try to retrieve the totalJoinTimeMs using this code:

```
long totalValidJoinTimeMs = playerStatsListener.getPlaybackStats().getTotalJoinTimeMs();
```

However, the app just crashes when I have included the above line of code.

Are there code examples of how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to `PlaybackStatsListener` to be called when the `PlaybackStats` is ready. You can use the following snippet to read analytics stats from exoplayer:

```
       player.addAnalyticsListener(new PlaybackStatsListener(true, new PlaybackStatsListener.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStatsReady(AnalyticsListener.EventTime eventTime, PlaybackStats playbackStats) {
                // read PlaybackStats fields or call methods here
                playbackStats.getTotalJoinTimeMs();
                ...
            }
        }));
```